# frozen and hashable dataclass with Iterable field

Tags: python, converters, python-dataclasses, python-attrs

Now that I have finally dropped support for Python 2, I am migrating from `attrs` to Python 3 `dataclasses` and there is one issue I am particularly struggling with.

Let's say I have a frozen and hashable class `MyClass` with one field `my_field` of type `tuple`.

Thanks to `attrs` converters, I was able to provide a flexible API, with clients able to instantiate `my_field` with a variety of types like `list`, `set` or `dict_keys`. They would all be automatically converted to a `tuple` before the class creation.

Can I preserve this API with `dataclasses`?

As requested, a small code sample:

```
@attr.s(frozen=True, hash=True)
class MyClass:
    my_field = attr.ib(default=tuple(), converter=tuple)


print(MyClass([1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: There is likely a solution to your problem. Only your question does not contain [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and it is difficult to see how exactly you perform your conversion. Please provide a complete example.

Comment: Hi sophros, I thought it would be self explanatory in the context of my question as attrs provides a converter argument. I have added a snippet nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the attribute value through the base class in post_init step seems to work:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyClass:
    my_field: Sequence[str]

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__setattr__('my_field', tuple(getattr(self, 'my_field')))
```

Mixin implementation:

```
class ValidationError(AttributeError):
    pass


class ConversionValidationField(Field):

    def __init__(self, default=MISSING, default_factory=MISSING, init=True, repr=True,
                 hash=None, compare=True, metadata=None, converter=None, validator=None):
        self.converter = converter
        self.validator = validator
        super().__init__(default, default_factory, init, repr, hash, compare, metadata)


class ConversionValidationMixin:

    def __post_init__(self):
        for field in fields(self):
            if isinstance(field, ConversionValidationField):
                if field.converter:
                    super().__setattr__(field.name, field.converter(getattr(self, field.name)))

                if field.validator:
                    if not field.validator(getattr(self, field.name)):
                        raise ValidationError('Validation failed for {}.'.format(field.name))
```

Answer (score 1):

No, converters are one of the things the dataclass PEP chose not to implement to keep is simple. http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/why.html#data-classes mentions a few more.

DCs are strictly a subset of `attrs` and it's unlikely that it'll ever change.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was hoping there may be a trick to emulate the conversion step before the class is frozen, maybe through some metaclass. It's a shame that the conversion feature was not included.